# How to change Windows cursor in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mouse-cursor

I like to change the cursor, when user clicks a button. I can use FrameworkElement.Cursor. But it only changes the cursor for my current App.

But I need my entire Windows cursor should change. I mean if you move the mouse outside the my app, it should show my cursor (not the default arrow).

How to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to change the cursor for the environment outside your app?

Comment: You need to make a Win32 call using PInvoke.

Comment: For an example, I am doing an eyedropper control for wpf like the one Expression Blend and Visual Studio designer. I want to choose the color outside my app also. I did that. Now I am trying to change the cursor. But I dont have any idea.

Comment: That is a valid case (color eye dropper) for changing the system cursor. Next time, please include in your question *why* you want to do something as that will significantly improve the answers you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this you have to change a registry value then perform an API call, check this MSDN post for more details on how to do it:

[How to change the system’s cursor using Visual C#.NET?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/977e2f40-3222-4e13-90ea-4e8d0cdf289c/)

Also check this link:

[Changing global mouse cursor OR cursor scheme with C#?](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=80020)